# Scoring two sequences of ordered numbers for their similarity to one-another

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, pattern-recognition

How would I go about scoring two sequences of numbers such that

`5, 8, 28, 31 (differences of 3, 20 and 3)
6, 9, 26, 29 differences of 3, 17 and 3`

are considered similar "enough" but a sequence of

`8 11 31 34` (differences of 3, 20 and 3, errors of 3, 3, 3, 3)

Is too dissimilar to allow?

The second set of numbers has an absolute error of

`1 1 2 2` and that is low "enough" to accept.

If that error was too high I'd like to be able to reject it.

To give a little background, these are indicators of time and when events arrived to a computer. The first sequence is the expected time of arrival and the second sequence is the actual times they arrived. Knowing that the sequence is at least in the correct order I need to be able to score the similarity to the expectation and accept or reject it by tweaking some sort of value.

If it were standard deviation for a set of numbers where order didn't matter I could just reject the second set based on its own standard deviation.

Since this is not the case I had the idea of measuring deviance and position error.

Position error shouldn't exceed 3, though this number should not be integer - it needs to be decimal as the numbers are more realistically floating point, or at least accurate to 6 decimal places.

It also needs to work equally well, or perhaps offer a variant in which a much longer series of numbers can be scored fairly.

In the longer series of numbers it it not likely the position error will exceed 3 so the position error would still be fairly low.

This is a partial solution I have found using a Person's correlation coefficient series for each time x fits into y. It uses the form of the equation that works off expected values. The comments describe it fairly well.

```
function getPearsonsCorrelation(x, y)
{
    /**
     * Pearsons can be calculated in an alternative fashion as
     * p(x, y) = (E(xy) - E(x)*E(y))/sqrt[(E(x^2)-(E(x))^2)*(E(y^2)-(E(y))^2)]
     * where p(x, y) is the Pearson's correlation result, E is a function referring to the expected value
     * E(x) = var expectedValue = 0; for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i ++){ expectedValue += x[i]*p[i] }
     *  where p[i] is the probability of that variable occurring, here we substitute in 1 every time
     *  hence this simplifies to E(x) = sum of all x values
     * sqrt is the square root of the result in square brackets
     * ^2 means to the power of two, or rather just square that value
     **/
    var maxdelay = y.length - x.length; // we will calculate Pearson's correlation coefficient at every location x fits into y
    var xl = x.length
    var results = [];

    for(var d = 0; d <= maxdelay; d++){
        var xy = [];
        var x2 = [];
        var y2 = [];
        var _y = y.slice(d, d + x.length); // take just the segment of y at delay

        for(var i = 0; i < xl; i ++){
            xy.push(x[i] * _y[i]); // x*y array
            x2.push(x[i] * x[i]); // x squareds array
            y2.push(_y[i] * _y[i]); // y squareds array
        }

        var sum_x = 0;
        var sum_y = 0;
        var sum_xy = 0;
        var sum_x2 = 0;
        var sum_y2 = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < xl; i ++){
            sum_x += x[i]; // expected value of x
            sum_y += _y[i]; // expected value of y
            sum_xy += xy[i]; // expected value of xy/n
            sum_x2 += x2[i]; // expected value of (x squared)/n
            sum_y2 += y2[i]; // expected value of (y squared)/n
        }

        var numerator = xl * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y; // expected value of xy - (expected value of x * expected value of y)
        var denomLetSide = xl * sum_x2 - sum_x * sum_x; // expected value of (x squared) - (expected value of x) squared
        var denomRightSide = xl * sum_y2 - sum_y * sum_y; // expected value of (y squared) - (expected value of y) squared
        var denom = Math.sqrt(denomLetSide * denomRightSide);
        var pearsonsCorrelation = numerator / denom;

        results.push(pearsonsCorrelation);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Duly noted mate :)

Comment: Ignoring gaps and positions, I would build the score by summing up the squared differences and divide it by the amount of numbers in the sequence to normalize it, this average error can now be compared to a constant threshold.